# How to print ASCII table with curses

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm trying to print an ASCII table, but the characters that appear are `^N^O^P^Q^R^S`, etc.

To make an RPG engine I need to put the ASCII table on the screen for the user select the tile

```
for (i = 0; i < 256; i++){
     wprintw(tiles_window, "%c", i);
}
```

However as I said, this just shows `^A^L^C` ...

Comment: I would also utter a lot of curses if I were tasked with printing the ASCII table for no apparent purpose.

Comment: Also note that you have to make provisions for non-printable characters, like "M (carriage return, ascii 13).  SUGGESTION: Please 1)  clarify exactly what you're trying to do (in more detail), 2) show some sample code (where you're having problems).

Comment: @JohnColeman: I wonder how his teacher would react if OP would take the assignment literal …

Comment: `ncurse` has nothing to do with printing control characters. `ncurse` is for generating escape sequence for terminal capabilities. I think what you wanted to know is which or what type of terminal can display control characters. In the old `DOS` world, such terminals exist where `^D` is displayed as a spade. Again this is what the terminal represents such non printing characters.

Answer (score 2):

(n)curses will display *printable* information.  It handles certain control characters specially, such as tab, newline, carriage return, backspace (see the [addch](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html) manual page).  Every character has a printable form.  You can use `keyname` for this — and it will show control characters as `^A`, etc.  However, using [`keyname`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-keyname_key_name), you can ensure that the special characters which `addch` could use for positioning are in printable form.

Your example might look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 256; i++){
         wprintw(tiles_window, "%4s ", keyname(i));
    }
```

to produce something like this:

```
  ^@   ^A   ^B   ^C   ^D   ^E   ^F   ^G   ^H   ^I   ^J   ^K   ^L   ^M   ^N   ^O
  ^P   ^Q   ^R   ^S   ^T   ^U   ^V   ^W   ^X   ^Y   ^Z   ^[   ^\   ^]   ^^   ^_
        !    "    #    $    %    &    '    (    )    *    +    ,    -    .    /
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    :    ;    <    =    >    ?
   @    A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J    K    L    M    N    O
   P    Q    R    S    T    U    V    W    X    Y    Z    [    \    ]    ^    _
   `    a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h    i    j    k    l    m    n    o
   p    q    r    s    t    u    v    w    x    y    z    {    |    }    ~   ^?
M-^@ M-^A M-^B M-^C M-^D M-^E M-^F M-^G M-^H M-^I M-^J M-^K M-^L M-^M M-^N M-^O
M-^P M-^Q M-^R M-^S M-^T M-^U M-^V M-^W M-^X M-^Y M-^Z M-^[ M-^\ M-^] M-^^ M-^_
 M-   M-!  M-"  M-#  M-$  M-%  M-&  M-'  M-(  M-)  M-*  M-+  M-,  M--  M-.  M-/
 M-0  M-1  M-2  M-3  M-4  M-5  M-6  M-7  M-8  M-9  M-:  M-;  M-<  M-=  M->  M-?
 M-@  M-A  M-B  M-C  M-D  M-E  M-F  M-G  M-H  M-I  M-J  M-K  M-L  M-M  M-N  M-O
 M-P  M-Q  M-R  M-S  M-T  M-U  M-V  M-W  M-X  M-Y  M-Z  M-[  M-\  M-]  M-^  M-_
 M-`  M-a  M-b  M-c  M-d  M-e  M-f  M-g  M-h  M-i  M-j  M-k  M-l  M-m  M-n  M-o
 M-p  M-q  M-r  M-s  M-t  M-u  M-v  M-w  M-x  M-y  M-z  M-{  M-|  M-}  M-~ M-^?
```

Comment: I pointed that out in my answer.  However, doing it this way allows you to print `^H` (backspace), `^I` (tab), `^J` (line-feed), `^M` (carriage return).  There *is* no portable way to print a single character for all 256 codes.

Comment: So, how can i print ?